# New Bicycle Advice? See detailed Specs Below

Tags: bike-fit, newbie

I am getting "snow blindness" and don't know where to start but the main thing is my new bicycle is my transportation every day sometimes for several hours and it's also my outlet to blow off steam. I've been riding for four years on a daily basis now and I've tried a good mix.

Infinity Fortified was excellent efficiency and weight, especially being incredibly tough(tested out more than I'd like to admit), but didn't like the seating profile of being pushed forward over the handlebars which I understand the purpose but like the Treks for comfort as I like to ride no hands sitting back sometimes. A couple of mongooses no luck there, Treks 3500, 3700, 4700 but being used bikes never got just the right fit and always wanted more speed. My specs order from most general to specific.

1. Reliable and tough w low maintenance (thinking for sure hardtail or hybrid).
2. Comfort with as much speed as possible without sacrificing the comfort(will ditch no-hands for a great ride experience)

3.NO FRONT DERAILLEUR...prefer a 9 Speed and up but number of back gears not a set req.

4. Light as possible/minimal interface with style but not carbon.
5. Averaging no less than 5-10 miles required daily w an additional 10 miles 2-4 times a week.
6. Need to be under $800 if possible, can probably up to $1100 but not planning for such at the moment. I Do all my own maintenance and adjusting within reason will gladly spend less for the initial unit and spend the time and money for modifications if means better for my needs.
7. Need RIGHT AWAY Lol. As long as it something I can get up and going ASAP.
8. Thought I should add I maximize tire pressure, accelerate explosively fast as possible every time, hit bumps w/o slowing just stand/hover so my sensitive area doesn't kill me lol. so disc brakes are req'd but there aren't any 100% dealbreakers either in this list so just your best educated and experienced advice for fairly new but courteous aggressive rider that never bought a new bike in my life.

I like what I can see from web on the Cannondale quick six if only it had a single hub instead of chainrings in the front but maybe spend the surplus on that mod? I'm 6 foot 200 pounds and fit I can do with a pro but just as a reference.

Thanks in advance for anyone putting the time in answering!! Please advise if anything out of sorts and/or request for further info.

Comment: I'd say given your budget and requirement for low maintenance, don't choose a hardtail. Choose a bike with absolutely no suspension at all, no suspension even in the fork.

Comment: Your point #7 really trumps everything else.  See what's available and pick the best of what is on offer.  If nothing is acceptable, wait and watch.

Comment: Why are you so set against a front derailleur? It only has a small weight penalty (not even 100% sure on that, big cassette sprockets are also heavy).

Comment: I agree with Juhist that cheap suspension is worse than none. But if you go over bumps and obstacles as brutal as you mention it might be worth stretching your budget to include an okay-ish front suspension fork.